# What does it mean when saved WhatsApp voice notes are not starting with "PTT"?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I deleted one of my contacts. I have a WhatsApp voice note, but it's not starting with "PTT". It's an alphanumeric number, and I could not find the mobile number associated. I can play it without any issue.

What does it mean when a WhatsApp voice message is saved other than a name starting with PTT? Why is it not stored with the mobile number details along with it?

Comment: It's not properly saved is my guess. Can you play it?

Comment: Yes I can play it ..

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely that voice note **wasn't created as as  push to talk** (PTT) message via WhatsApp in which case it normally starts with `PTTxxxxx`, rather this voice note was created with a device recorder hence starts with alphanumeric number.

I noticed my voice recorder names all recorded audios with in a number format to confirm this. Hence its still recognised snd plays well on your device. Perhaps they sent you an audio created by a native voice recorder not via WhatsApp.